# Highlighting ignored after changing settings

Tags: vim

I have the following python file:

[image]

As you can see all the python keywords are highlighted (except for `print`?). However, if I change the colorscheme:

```
:colo OceanicNext
```

And then change it back again:

```
:colo TextMate
```

Most of the python highlighting goes away:

[image]

The only way I can get the "original" colorscheme back is to close the file and then re-open it in vim. Why does this occur? And is there a better way to get back to the full original colorscheme without having to close and re-open the file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to source your vimrc config file.

> :source $MYVIMRC

Also If you have troubles with colorschemes/highlighting in python. You might want to take a look at [semshi](https://github.com/numirias/semshi) plugin for enhanced highlighting.

Comment: yea, doing `:source $MYVIMRC | edit!` doesn't do anything either.